# Add background video section to shopify

Tags: shopify

Currently my hero section used a gif on slideshow. I want to replace the gif with mp4 however slideshow doesn't support mp4 file. I'm thinking of using background video instead, but how do I implement that ? I only found that background video feature is available through premium app

https://pangeamovement.com/

Comment: You need to make changes or create a new section where using HTML and CSS you can achieve it, directly you can't add video in background like images in CSS.

Comment: is there any source or tutorial that I can follow ?

Comment: Here is the basic started codepan to have an idea, how to start over it. https://codepen.io/o-nkar/pen/dyNoJPe